# Update other fields during the save

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have declared a signal for the UserProfile model which updates some other fields. The stored data are coming from a web service.

```
 post_save.connect(user_profile_update, sender=UserProfile)
```

in user_profile_update, i did this:

```
 profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=instance) 
 profile.province = xml.duzeltilmisil #this comes from a web service
 profile.save()
```

and i got this error:

```
 'NoneType' object is not callable
 profile.save()
```

There is an other error but what did I do was also recursive. When I update UserProfile, it should trig user_profile_update again.

Is there any reasonable way to update those fields during the save?

Comment: disable the signal, and see if the error still occurs

Comment: karthikr, the user enters the postal address as a normal text, a webservice parses it and it gives me the city, district etc. information of the address and i want to store those information just after the update. so i think i need this signal. if i will disable the signal, i will not get any error but the address will not be parsed.

Comment: Why do you need a signal to do a parsing? You can handle it better in your view. Signals are good only for minor updates, not for implementing logic

Comment: Yeah, I am new at Django and that's a solution. If you will write the same thing as answer, it would be cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are parsing the address, it is a better approach to handle the parsing in the view, rather than as a signal.

Signals are normal used for minor updates to other models. .

So, your code can be:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=instance) 
profile.province = xml.duzeltilmisil #this comes from a web service

//parse the address here, and then save the models
profile.save()
```